# groovy regex to eliminate desired character & all characters succeeding to desired character?

Tags: groovy

How to eliminate the desired character & all the other characters succeeding that desired character.

```
def str1 = "value_of_string*123456"
```

Here, desired character is `"*"` , and post desired character is `"123456"`.
So, after removing them `str1` should look like `"value_of_string"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def str1 = "value_of_string*123456"

assert str1.takeWhile { it != '*' } == 'value_of_string'
assert str1.tokenize('*')[0] == 'value_of_string'
assert str1.split("\\*")[0] == 'value_of_string'
```

Comment: def str1 = "value_of_string*123456" , #DO something to remove * and post * characters , now str1 should have been removed * and post * characters.

Comment: How will you know the right hand side of these assert statements ("value_of_string") ? That's unknown in this case. It's  just a regex needed  to chip of * & post * chars of that string.

Comment: That is exactly what each of the approach does above (chipping of * and post * chars) .Above assertions were examples to showcase what you expect is what you get. You can try the above example with any string replacing "value_of_string".

Comment: sorry, my bad. Got it. Thank U.

Comment: Or `str1.find(/^[^*]+/​)​`